# How can I return focus to the previous window?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I have an Autohotkey script which opens and closes a pop-out command line similar to the Quake console dropdown. When I close it, however, it places focus on the taskbar. How can I instead return focus to the top window in the stack?

Comment: add a final ALT+Tab ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac I tried that, that takes it to the *second* window in the stack. I suppose I could do two alt-tabs, but that's an ugly kludge.

Answer (score 2):

```
WinGet, ActiveId, ID, A
WinWaitNotActive, ahk_id %ActiveId%
WinActivate, ahk_id %ActiveId%
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that my console window is set to stay on top, and is semi-transparent, so I can still work on other windows while it is up. Because of this, the window that is on top of the stack when I finish with the console may not be the same window that was active when I opened it.

Comment: I'm hoping for a way to access the Windows API and get the ID of the window on top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>. That return you to the previous focus program, instead of the next.

Comment: That takes me to the bottom window in the stack.

Comment: Then try alt-tab, then shift-alt-tab. But seems it will be faster to use just the mouse to click the program on the task bar.

Comment: Exactly why I'm looking for something to put in the AHK script to return focus to it.

Comment: In your AHK script, can you use `WinGetActiveTitle` to get the active window before opening the pop-up, then use `WinActivate` to switch back after?

Answer (score 0):

In your autohotkey script:

WinExist("A") ; get active window

; do your stuff

WinActivate() ; restore last found window

Alternatively you can also use: ActWin := WinActive("A") and WinActivate, ahk_id %ActWin%